# Formal negation of $((p\rightarrow q) \vee (q \leftrightarrow r)) \rightarrow q$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Can someone give me an outline for how I can negate the following?

$((p\rightarrow q) \vee (q \leftrightarrow r)) \rightarrow q$

Answer (score 1):

You want to work from the inside out. Call the inside of the outer parentheses $s$, so $s=(p\to q)\vee (q\leftrightarrow r)$.

Then, the desired negation is $\lnot (s\to q)$. How do we evaluate that? Well, what actually is $\to$? $s \to q$ means that if $s$ is true, then $q$ is true. If $s$ is false, it doesn't say anything. Thus, $(s\to q)$ is only false if $s$ is true and $q$ is false, or in other words, $\lnot (s\to q)=s \wedge (\lnot q)$

Another way to see this is with truth tables:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}s& q & s\to q&\lnot(s\to q)\\
T&T&T&F\\
T&F&F&T\\
F&T&T&F\\
F&F&T&F\end{array}$$

Expanding $s$ back out again gives $$((p\to q)\vee (q\leftrightarrow r))\wedge(\lnot q)$$

Answer (score -1):

¬((p → q) ∨ (q ↔ r)) → ¬ q
¬p → ¬q ∧ ¬q ↔ ¬r → ¬ q

Comment: You might want to format that with TeX and maybe add a couple of English words by way of explanation.

Comment: Some parenthesis or line breaks or something might be nice too.